# Is there any way to integrate Activiti BPM with web application

Tags: activiti, workflow-activity

I am new to Activiti BPM. I just wanted to implement with web application with activiti BPM with using maven dependency.How to do it.

Comment: I have same problem? do you solve your problem? and can you help me? thanks.

Comment: Hi @SSH, I havent used activiti BPM, Instead i developed my own plugin similar to Activiti BPM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should provide more details to make your problem landed. I built a test demo with configurations. Hope it help. [A configuration demo](https://github.com/hubnate/Activiti-demo)

**EDIT**: I parse the Spring applicationContext.xml here. Fix this xml to fit your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClass}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/java/actdemo/domain/entity/*.xml" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.java.actdemo.domain.entity" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Configurations for the Activiti process engine. -->
  <!-- A base configuration bean. Manage third-party plugins and Activiti functions. -->
  <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />

    <!-- A switch for all timer related functions -->
    <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />

    <!-- This property affects the auto-deployment function. -->
    <property name="deploymentResources"
      value="classpath*:/com/java/actdemo/domain/entity/bpmn/*.bpmn" />
    <property name="createDiagramOnDeploy" value="false" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Factory bean for building all services. This is the fundamental entry for 
    all users if Spring is not used. -->
  <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Activiti Beans for handling processes. -->
  <!-- The basic service for BPMN diagrams. Handle all deployment related function. 
    Mainly operate Deployment and ProcessDefinition. -->
  <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService" />

  <!-- The basic service for managing processes. Use this service to perform Start, 
    Stop, Update functions for any running process. Events and messages handling are 
    all here. Mainly operate Activity, ProcessInstance, and Execution. -->
  <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRuntimeService" />

  <!-- The basic service for managing user tasks. Manage how Tasks work, including 
    claiming, completing, unclaiming, etc. Mainly operate Task. -->
  <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getTaskService" />

  <!-- The service for querying historic data(related to history level). Mainly operate 
    HistoricVariableInstance, HistoricProcessInstance, etc. -->
  <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getHistoryService" />

  <!-- The service for managing timer related jobs and customized functions. Admin 
    functions and querying are here. Mainly operate Job. -->
  <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getManagementService" />

  <!-- Manage Activiti authority functions. Use this service to build user-group 
    relations. Mainly operate User, Group, Membership -->
  <bean id="identityService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getIdentityService" />

  <!-- This service operate form related functions like setting form variables, starting 
    processes with form data, completing tasks with form, etc. -->
  <bean id="formService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getFormService" />
</beans>
```

Here is the basic dependencies. I use Junit, Jackson, Spring-test and Mysql. You can remove them:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>Alfresco Maven Repository</id>
      <url>https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
      <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.15.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
      <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
      <version>5.15.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply, i want to create a workflow in integrate to my web project but i am not getting the way to start up.

Comment: @Mayur You should go to configuration first.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Activiti BPM with any any Web technology by exposing Activiti BPM as webservices. And you must know activiti BPM api's to play with it.